"Copying from template version None" Issue in Python Copier Templating Package
I've created a copier template. Everything is alright with it. I'm generating it within a Python file. When prompting/answering is finished, it shows a message that I don't know how I can modify/fix.
Copying from template version None
 identical  .
 create ...
 create ...

What is template version?! What does identical . mean here?!
I couldn't find any information about these two terms on its official docs.
